# Properties file from root dir not found

Tags: java, file-io, properties

My properties file is placed just under root dir of my webapp.

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("myfile.properties"));
```

gives:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myfile.properties
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you running your program from your IDE or from a jar file? It has some implications regarding where your properties file should be...

Comment: Root dir? Is it in the `System.getProperty("user.dir")`?

Comment: Running in IDE (Eclispe). With root dir I just mean the most upper dir where I develop my app.

Comment: `FileInputStream(String)` constructor will look under `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Comment: @iccthedral I think you're wrong. `new FileInpuStream(String)`  is equivalent to `new FileInputStream(new File(String))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb:

1. Add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to your code.
2. Go to the directory printed out.
3. Copy your property file to that location.

Answer (score 2):

put your properties file to WEB-INF/classes/ dir instead

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "/myfile.properties"? Your way of referring to the file will resolve the path relative to the location where the class is present, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes also tried this. Same error. But I do not want to make reference to the folder where the class is placed (in a package). I want to take the file from root. What would I have to change?